# Cordova plugin access

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to develop with cordova and visual studio 2015. When i install a plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-startapp for example) i see in it's readme the usage should be like: `navigator.startApp.<somemethods>` but all i get is error saying `startApp` is undefined.

Same with few other plugins.

I have this problem with imported Ionic sample project but also with default VSs cordova sample.

Pugins seems to install fine, folder structure is created, VS says installation was successful.

Are those readme docs outdated? Or do i need to somehow "register" installed plugin?

Comment: are you waiting for device ready event before trying to use the plugins?

Comment: I belive I am. Plugin usage is under a button click which is on another tab. Ctrl+Space is not even showing plugins functionality. For startapp Visual should prompt navigator.startApp according to startapps docs. There is no startApp in navigator.*

Comment: Verify that device ready is actually firing.  You could be hitting an unhandled JavaScript exception before the debugger attaches.  Add an event listener for the deviceready event and log a console message.  Next, once the debugger attaches type window.location.reload() to force the page to re-init and see if you find any new JavaScript exceptions.  Do you see anything?